# Stuck in Proof of a Corallary to the Sylow Theorems

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Corallary: If $G$ is a finite group with $N \trianglelefteq G$, and if $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N$ with $P\trianglelefteq N$, then $P\trianglelefteq G$.

I understand the proof given in my book until the last statement, which is the following.

$P$ is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N$, hence $g^{-1}Pg=P$ for all $g \in G$ and $P \trianglelefteq G$ as claimed.

$P$ is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N$ implies $g^{-1}Pg=P$ for all $g \in N.$

How do they get from that to $g^{-1}Pg=P$ for all $g \in G?$

I have seen the discussion of a very similar proposition on this forum and it didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

More generally, this is true for [characteristic subgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup). Regular normal subgroups are fixed by [inner automorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism) (that is, conjugation) but characteristic subgroups are fixed by *all* automorphisms.

Since $P \leq N$ is the *unique* subgroup of order $|P|$, it must be fixed by *every automorphism* of $N$ (do you see why? As a hint, every subgroup is sent to a subgroup of the same order by an automorphism).

Then we notice that conjugation by $g \in G$ is an automorphism of $N$ (since $N$ is normal in $G$). So then $P$ must be fixed by it. So $P$ is normal in $G$ as well.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks. I have a tough time with math that is mostly words.

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. If this answered your question, you should mark it as such by clicking the checkmark to the left. That way other users know how to spend their time

Answer (score 1):

Conjugation by an element of the group defines an automorphism,  and thus carries a $p $-Sylow subgroup to a $p $- Sylow subgroup.